Seeing "originalFactory is undefined" in non-production Next.js application
I have a Next.js (14.2.1) application that I am deploying in both production and non-production versions. When I deploy in production I do this:
npm run build
npm run start &

When I deploy in non-production I do this:
npm run dev &

When I first load a page in the non-production instance I see this error: originalFactory is undefined. If I hit F5 (refresh page) the page comes up and will not re-appear unless I restart the instance.
This error never appears in the production instance. How can I get the non-production instance to stop raising this error?
